# contar los días de la semana de la fecha actual sin domingos

Tags: php

Buenas como seguir contando los días que no sean domingos.

Por ejemplo si quiero insertar la fecha dentro de 6 días que no tome en cuanta el domingo es decir si hoy es lunes dentro de 6 días es domingo que me inserte el día lunes o si hoy es jueves y dentro de 4  días es lunes que inserte el día martes, que no tome en cuenta los dias domingos.
e intentado algo asi:

```
$nombredia = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", time()) . " + 6 day"));
$dias = array('','Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo');
$fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($nombredia))];
echo $fecha;
echo $nombredia;

if($fecha =='Domingo')
{
    $nombredia = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", time()) . " + 7 day"));
    echo $nombredia;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Siempre quieres ignorar el día domingo?

http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
$arrayConDias = array('','Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo');
$FechaAhora = new Datetime();
$FechaAhora->add(new DateInterval('P6D'));
if ($FechaAhora->format('N') == 7){
  // Si es domingo, agrego un día.
  $FechaAhora->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
echo $arrayConDias[$FechaAhora->format('N')];
```

Comment: si, pero para que me diera el formato de y-m-d

Comment: Tendrías que poner: $FechaAhora->format('Y-m-d')

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco si esta sea la forma más fácil de hacer lo que pides, pero se me ocurrió la siguiente función que cuenta los días a partir de cualquier fecha, sin incluir el día que tu decidas, y devuelve la fecha correspondiente a la fecha inicial mas los días contados.

Funciona con un "array" que representa los días de la semana. Puse un "1" los días que quieres tomar en cuenta y "0" los que quieres omitir, empezando desde lunes, martes,... etc.

[NOTA] - Si los calculos se van a hacer con respecto a `$start_date = date(); // O sea "now"`, verificar que la zona horaria "timezone" de php.ini este bien configurada.

```
<?php

function sumar_dias($start_date, $num_days) {
    $wday_value = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0); // lun, mar, mie...
    $Dateobj = new DateTime($start_date);
    $j = intval($Dateobj->format('N') - 1); // Indice inicial array.
    $day_sum = 0;
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $num_days) {
        $j++; // incrementa 1 dia.
        if($j == 7) { // Si llega al final de array (final de la semana)
            $j = 0;
        }
        if($wday_value[$j] == 0) {
            // Si cae en un dia que no se quiere contar, 
            // hacer que el while itere una vez mas
            $i--;
        } 
        $day_sum++;
        $i++;
    }
    $Dateobj->modify('+'.$day_sum.' day');
    return $Dateobj->format('Y-m-d');
}

// valores de test
echo sumar_dias('2018-09-24', 5);
echo sumar_dias('2018-09-24', 6);
echo sumar_dias('2018-09-24', 25);
echo sumar_dias('2018-09-24', 30);
```

Resultado

```
2018-09-29 // Sabado
2018-10-01 // Lunes
2018-10-23 // Martes
2018-10-29 // Lunes
```